# Android Views only allow one Listener at a time?

Tags: android

Looking through the Android View code (specifically at RadioButton and RadioGroup), I see that both classes only allow one Listener at a time (externally provided -- they have their own internal listeners too). Setting a second Listener just overwrites:

E.g., in RadioGroup:

```
public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
    mOnCheckedChangeListener = listener;
}
```

I'd assumed a set of Listeners would be kept (or chained), and iterated through on an event broadcast. Instead, whichever listener is last set "wins". That seems fragile.

What's the rationale for this?

Comment: You can always extend OnCheckedChangeListener like MyOnCheckedChangeListener and call super from subclass if you want to keep default listener.

Comment: NAA, but I don't consider this fragile. When you set a listener, you should know *exactly* what method it's going to call from that point on. You shouldn't need to worry about what listener was attached to it before. If you need something more, you can extend/alter it for a specific use, but I don't think it should be the default.

Answer (score 1):

This is primarily done to handle things like UI layering. For example you might have the background, with `View A` on top of it that handles clicks - but You show `View B` above `A` when the user clicks a button. Now if you click `B`, you don't want `A` to respond. It's meant as a simplification.

As stated in the comments, certain events can return `false` after handling a click, for example, so that the next layer can handle the event.

If you do create a reference to all of the Objects waiting to hear from a click event, you can use an ordered data structure, such as an `ArrayList`, to ensure that the order an event is handled is not random.

For example, start with an *interface* that has a method that returns `true` or `false`. `OnCheckedChange` does not do this (moved the `d`'s:

```
public interface OnCheckChangedListener {
    public boolean onCheckChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
}
```

Now create a subclass of `RadioGroup` with the following global variable:

```
private List<OnCheckChangedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<OnCheckChangedListener>();
```

Then have the methods:

```
public void addOnCheckChangedListener(OnCheckChangedListener listener) {
    this.listeners.add(listener);
}

public void removeOnCheckChangedListener(OnCheckChangedListener listener) {
    this.listeners.remove(listener);
}
```

Then in your constructor, just add this:

```
this.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChange(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
            if (listeners.get(i).onCheckChanged(buttonView, isChecked))
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Now all of the listeners will have a chance to respond, but the order will be handled like `onClick` or `onTouch`. You can also not call `break`, and just let all the listeners get called (in order).